# How to access stdout as part of a create_subprocess_shell coroutine?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-asyncio

I'm writing a python script that calls 3 shell scripts for each one of hundreds of subfolders . These scripts make ls calls to AWS S3 that are slow to receive responses from the server, so I've decided to code this asynchronously.

I've modeled a simpler version of the problem where I call three shell scripts for each of three participants. For the sake of my understanding how to call shell scripts asynchronously, the shell scripts I'm using below do not ping AWS, they just print random numbers. I'm just trying to capture the output of randomList.sh and return it as a list (or other data type that I'll decide on later).

**My Question**: How do I access the output from my script calls?

```
#randomList.sh

x=$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 ))
echo "sleeping for $x for $1"
sleep $x
x=$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 ))
echo "sleeping for $x for $1"
sleep $x
x=$(( ( RANDOM % 10 )  + 1 ))
echo "sleeping for $x for $1"
sleep $x
```

```
import asyncio
import subprocess

async def callScript(script, participant):
    call = "./" + script + " " + participant
    proc = asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(call, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    result = await proc
    #HELP!
    #this is where i'm not sure how to access stdout..
    output = result.communicate()
    print(output)
    return output


async def callParticipant(participant):
    script1 = 'randomList.sh'
    script2 = 'randomList1.sh'
    script3 = 'randomList2.sh'
    scriptCalls = []
    scriptCalls.append(asyncio.create_task(callScript(script1, participant)))
    scriptCalls.append(asyncio.create_task(callScript(script2, participant)))
    scriptCalls.append(asyncio.create_task(callScript(script3, participant)))
    results = await asyncio.gather(*scriptCalls)
    return results

async def getRows():
    participants = ["1","2","3"]
    tasks = []
    for participant in participants:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(callParticipant(participant)))
    rows = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return rows

rows = asyncio.run(getRows())
```

---

**EDIT, solved it myself**
See the callScript function. Note that I also put `rows = asyncio.run(getRows())` into a `main()` function, but that was unrelated to the solution.

```
async def callScript(script, participant):
    call = "./" + script + " " + participant
    #I CHANGED THE FOLLOWING LINES
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(call, stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout = await proc.communicate()
    output = stdout[0]
    output = output.decode('ascii')
    output = output.split()
    return output


async def callParticipant(participant):
    script1 = 'randomList.sh'
    script2 = 'randomList1.sh'
    script3 = 'randomList2.sh'
    scriptCalls = []
    scriptCalls.append(asyncio.create_task(callScript(script1, participant)))
    scriptCalls.append(asyncio.create_task(callScript(script2, participant)))
    scriptCalls.append(asyncio.create_task(callScript(script3, participant)))
    results = await asyncio.gather(*scriptCalls)
    return results

async def getRows():
    participants = ["1","2","3"]
    tasks = []
    for participant in participants:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(callParticipant(participant)))
    rows = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return rows

def main ():
    rows = asyncio.run(getRows())
    print(rows)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `await` function

```
-- your code until --
rows = asyncio.run(getRows())
result = await rows
```

you can read more about how it realy works in:
[https://www.aeracode.org/2018/02/19/python-async-simplified/#:~:text=When%20you%20have%20an%20asynchronous,result%20when%20you%20await%20me%22](https://www.aeracode.org/2018/02/19/python-async-simplified/#:%7E:text=When%20you%20have%20an%20asynchronous,result%20when%20you%20await%20me%22).

this example runs fine:

```
async def get_chat_id(name):
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    return "chat-%s" % name

async def main():
    id_coroutine = get_chat_id("django")
    result = await id_coroutine
```

Comment: I didn't know i could use await outside of a coroutine function. Implementing your fix, I get the error: ```SyntaxError: 'await' outside function```

Comment: thanks, but not the answer i was looking for. i was looking for help with the async subprocess calls. my solution is posted above.